# What does "Blockwise" in execute mode do?

Tags: vimrc

I have the following in a .vimrc file:

`vmap ; :Blockwise<SPACE>`

I'm not sure what the `Blockwise` key word does.

Comment: I can't find it in the documentation, maybe it's part of a plugin?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680549/what-is-blockwise-motion-in-vim

Comment: `:verb vmap ;` to see where it is defined. Must be a plugin, so read its description.

Comment: If you don't know what it does, why do you have it in your .vimrc?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt He said in `a` .vimrc file not specifically `his` .vimrc

Comment: @Ashok Then he should ask the owner of this particular vimrc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an Ex command, and since its first character is written in uppercase, it's probably a custom command.

To see what it does, and where it was defined, you can use this command:

```
:verbose command Blockwise
```

… or shorter:

```
:verb com Blockwise
```

---

By default, an Ex command operates on whole lines.

So, for example, suppose you wanted to perform a substitution inside a column in a paragraph. You could visually select it, then type `:s/pattern/replacement/g`. You could think that the substitution command would replace the occurrences of `pattern` with `replacement` only inside the block, but since Ex commands operates on whole lines, `:s` would replace `pattern` anywhere in the paragraph, not just inside the column you selected.

As a workaround, inside the pattern, you could use the atom `\%V` (see `:h /\%V`), but it may not be always as simple for other commands (other than `:s`).

With your mapping, if you hit `;` in visual mode, Vim will write on the command line `:'<,'>Blockwise`.

So, it's just a guess, but your `:Blockwise` command probably expects as an argument another command, and limits the effect of the latter on a visual blockwise selection. It may be a mechanism to enable all or most of Vim Ex commands to operate on blockwise selection, and not just whole lines.

With it, you could probably do something like:

```
:'<,'>Blockwise s/pattern/replacement/g
```

… to replace `pattern` with `replacement`, only inside the visual block.

---

When you find the name of a command which you don't know, you can try to look for it inside the help, with the `:helpgrep` or `:lhelpgrep` command. The latter can be shortened into `:lh`. Currently, if I type:

```
:lh :Blockwise
```

I don't have any results, so with this you would know it's not a default Vim command. However, if it has been installed with a plugin which has some documentation, then it's possible that the previous command returns some results.

---

You probably want to replace `:vmap`, with `:xnoremap`. In front of a `:map` command, `v` doesn't mean `visual mode`, it means `visual mode`+`select mode`. `x` stands for visual mode only. So, if you use `:vmap`, you will bind a printable character (`;`) in `select mode`. And the help says that it could be confusing to a user (`:h mapmode-x`):

```
NOTE: Mapping a printable character in Select mode may confuse the user.
```

You could change your mapping like this:

```
xnoremap ; :Blockwise<Space>
```